# React - Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'WBSAutoFillFormTypeUndetermined' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs

getting this console error in React dev environment... I see some similar questions but I am not seeing a question with this exact same message.  trying to pinpoint where this is coming from - any tips appreciated.
thanks in advance!

```
content_script.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'WBSAutoFillFormTypeUndetermined' has already been declared
```

This error comes up inconsistently - sometimes when I load a component, sometimes not... can reproduce error inconsistently.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

this console error was coming from the Apple "iCloud Passwords" chrome extension.  I deactivated the extension & the errors disappeared.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  I didn't even know I had installed the iCloud Passwords plugin.  But yeah, that was the problem.  And I have been wondering why all my websites were giving this crazy error.

Comment: It was the iCloud extension for me too.

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from the iCloud chrome extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).