# Why do I keep getting a console error when using VS Code and Live Server?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I'm in the process of learning Javascript. I installed the Live Server extension on VS Code, as well as typing "live-server" into the terminal, to see Chrome's console update upon save. Whenever I have a live server up, I keep getting this message in red in the console:

> VM4057 content_script.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'WBSAutoFillFormTypeUndetermined' has already been declared (at VM4057 content_script.js:1:1)

The only thing I have at 1:1 is `'use strict';`, but even if I remove that I still get the message. All code works otherwise. Is there something I can change to make it stop? And just to be clear, I use either the extension or type live-server. Never both at the same time.

Comment: are you by any chance using Apple "iCloud Passwords" chrome plugin? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67236133/5334486

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the Apple's chrome plugin "iCloud Passwords". Deactivate or remove it and the error will disappear.